# javascript: get object from array when I know id

Tags: javascript

this is my array in js:

```
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test1',  
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test2',  
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test3',  
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test4',  
  }
]
```

and I only need to grab the object where I know its id and assign it to a variable.
I know that I will need an object with id number 1 so I would like to:

```
const item = {
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test1',  
  },
```

Comment: `array.prototype.filter` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) :

```js
const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    title: "test1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userId: 1,
    title: "test2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    userId: 1,
    title: "test3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    userId: 1,
    title: "test4"
  }
];

const item = array.find(({ id }) => id === 1);

console.log(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array` has a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function on its prototype that allows you to filter the values using a function, which gets passed each value in the array in turn. If the condition you specify in your function returns true, your value is returned.

So in this case:

```
const myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test1',  
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test2',  
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test3',  
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    userId: 1,
    title: 'test4',  
  }
]

const idToFind = 1;

const foundValues = myArray.filter(item => item.id === idToFind)
```

Then if you knew only one value would you found, you would just take the first item in the foundValues array:

```
const foundItem = foundValues[0]
```